# Send device token to WKWebView using evaluateJavaScript

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

So my entire Swift app is built using a WKWebView. I'm trying to prompt the user to opt into push notifications, and then if they accept, send their device token to the browser (via `evaluateJavaScript`) so that I can save it into the database.

I have the prompt working, and this is my callback once they opt into the notifications (Inside `AppDelegate.swift`):

```
var mainView = ViewController()
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    let characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet( charactersInString: "<>" )

    let deviceTokenString: String = ( deviceToken.description as NSString )
        .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet( characterSet )
        .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "" ) as String

    mainView.sendDeviceTokenId(deviceTokenString);
}
```

If I `print` `deviceTokenString`, it logs the device token successfully.

In my main `ViewController.swift`, I have my `setDeviceTokenId` which is being called once I have found the device token:

```
func sendDeviceTokenId(newToken: String) {
    self.deviceToken = newToken
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("saveDeviceIdFromWebview('" + self.deviceToken + "')", completionHandler: nil)
}
```

`self.deviceToken` is set successfully, although no Javascript is ever called on my page.

I have tons of other areas within my code that uses `evaluateJavaScript`, and they all work successfully, besides this one call. Such as this one that simply calls a function in my webview that passes in a saved username from a actionlist:

```
func loadCredentialsToForm(selectedCredentials: AnyObject) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("loadSavedCredentialsFromWebview('" + selectedCredentials["key"] as! String! + "', true)", completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I decided to try and run the call within my `userContentController` instead, it called the function within my site perfectly, although unfortunately, it is called far too early since the user hasn't signed up for the notifications yet.

I've set breakpoints to make sure that the `sendDeviceTokenId` function is called after the webview is loaded, and it's definitely called long after the WKWebView has been successfully loaded.

My question is, why isn't my Javascript function being called once the user signs up for push notifications?